# C# project runs with no errors but doesn't add anything in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add records into my C# project and it runs with no errors but it doesn't add anything in the database:

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (admNo.Text != "" & session.Text != "" & name.Text != "")
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\Divya Pathak\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SchoolRecord\\SchoolRecord\\Database1.sdf");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into addNew (no,session,name) values ('" + admNo.Text + "', '" + session.Text + "', '" + name.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully", "mission successfull");
    }
}
```

Could someone please advise why?

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. The editor allows you to indent and you can indent by putting four spaces before text on any given line. Others won't be able to read your code and help you without it being readable.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @jlafay - you should just edit the post rather than making comments like that.

Comment: @PreetSangha, yes I do usually edit posts and I apologize for not doing so previously. I saw the question before bed last night and didn't have time to edit it. Instead, I left a quick comment to the OP since they are new to the community to give them some pointers on how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 5):

you need to set `cm.Connection` as `cn`

```
cm.Connection =cn;
```

OR

```
using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection("connection string"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert addNew (no,session,name) values (@no,@session,@name)", cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", admNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", session.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[This](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) will help you to write the correct  connection string for SQL CE

Comment: And highly recommended to use the `Using` statement AND use `cmd.Parameters`.

Answer (score 4):

You have four mistakes:

1. You never associate the connection with the command
2. You're connecting to a Sql Server Compact database using the full Sql Server provider (you should be using the SqlCe namespace:
3. You're building your query using unsafe string concatenation instead of query parameters. **Fix this!**
4. Your connection won't be closed if an exception is thrown, which can ultimately lock you out of your database. You need to close the connection as part of a `finally` block, and the easiest way to do this is with a `using` block.

.

```
using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into addNew (no,session,name) values (@no,@session,@name)", cn))
{
    //guessing at column lengths:
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(admNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@session", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = session.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = name.Text;

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```